# OS X: let scutil use stored secret when connecting L2TP VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, terminal.app

This is a follow-up question of [Start configured VPN from command line (OSX)](https://superuser.com/questions/358513/start-configured-vpn-from-command-line-osx).

I tried the answer by @encoded, which suggests the following command:

`scutil --nc start [A-name-of-VPN-configuration-stored-in-Network-Preferences]`

It works nicely for PPTP connection, but for L2TP, this command fails to read the shared secret stored in that configuration, and I need to provide `--secret [shared-secret]` for L2TP connection.

This is obviously not safe enough; I want `scutil` to be aware of the secret stored instead of asking me. As it can read stored username and password, this should be only a small tweak, but I can't figure out what it is.

I'm running OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.

Comment: There is working [alternative answer](http://superuser.com/a/557390/624525) in that thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start configured VPN from command line (OSX)](https://superuser.com/questions/358513/start-configured-vpn-from-command-line-osx)